# Efficient way of finding the most recent document in multiple groups MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a chat MongoDB database that has the following collections:

```js
chats: {
  chat_id: string, // indexed 1, unique
  last_updated: number, // indexed -1
  // other data...
}
```

```js
messages: {
  chat_id: string; // indexed 1
  message_id: string; // indexed 1, unique
  timestamp: number; // indexed -1
  // other data...
}
```

I would like to be able to query for 10 most recent chats and receive the chat document and the most recent message associated with that chat. Currently, what I'm doing is:

```js
// step 1: find the 10 most recent chats
const chats = await db.collection('chats')
  .find()
  .sort({last_updated: -1})
  .limit(10)
  .toArray();

// step 2: use $group to find the most recent message in each chat
const messages = await db.collection('messages').aggregate([
  { $match: { chat_id: { $in: chats.map(chat => chat.chat_id) } } },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  { $group: { _id: '$chat_id', latest_message: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }
]).toArray();
```

I'm worried that the $sort and $group stages will be slow if chats have lots of messages associated with them. Is there a better way to do this or am I prematurely trying to optimize something that will work fine?

Comment: I think you should try doing this as a single aggregation pipeline and use $lookup (with an embedded pipeline) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider that your current approach is correct and should work fine, even if your chats would have lots of messages associated with them.

> I'm worried that the $sort and $group stages will be slow if chats have lots of messages associated with them. Is there a better way to do this or am I prematurely trying to optimize something that will work fine?

Yes, there is a better more efficient way to do this if there are many chats in your database and each chat has a relatively small number of messages.

Instead of using the `$group` stage to find the most recent message in each chat, you can use the `$lookup` stage to join the messages collection and find the most recent message directly:

```
const chats = await db.collection('chats')
  .find()
  .sort({last_updated: -1})
  .limit(10)
  .toArray();

const messages = await db.collection('messages')
 .aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: {
      from: 'chats',
      localField: 'chat_id',
      foreignField: 'chat_id',
      as: 'chat'
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$chat' },
  { $sort: { 'chat.last_updated': -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
.toArray();

const joinedChats = chats.map((chat, index) => {
  chat.latest_message = messages[index];
  return chat;
});
```

I hope it can help you.

P.s.
You should choose the most appropriate approach for you.

For example, if you have many chats with a relatively small number of messages, then the approach which I provided may be more efficient for you.

However, if you have less chats with a large number of messages, then your approach is  more sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, I really appreciate it. I'm pretty sure the amount of chats I will have will be >> the amount of messages I have, so I think I will end up using this method. Thanks!